# Minor edit on Error code

Tags: discussion

Consider this [question here](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/q/3583/18061) as an example. The question here contains a Screenshot which describes the error code.

Example Screenshot present in the question :
[image: Example Screenshot]

I believe that adding the error code as a text in such questions would be useful. This would improve the search presence of the question (text inside the images cannot be indexed by search engines). This would make sense seeing the fact that Stackexchange sites are supposed to get 90% of their traffic from Search engines[[Ref]](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/20757/windows-phone).

But on the other hand this is minor edit which will not improve the readability of the question. I know such edits are not discouraged by the community.

Can we allow edits that adds error code to the questions from screenshots? Or should such edits be avoided?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having the error code in the question text would definitely be useful. I would even go so far as to quote the full error message in the question text and remove the screenshot entirely, as it doesn't really add anything useful, but instead pushes the rest of the question as well as comments and answers further down the page. Alternatively, the screenshot could be cropped to remove the non-essential parts.

When reviewing suggested edits, the option to reject trivial ones is summarised thusly:

> This edit does not make the post even a little bit easier to read, easier to find, more accurate or more accessible. Changes are either completely superfluous or actively harm readability.

As you said, having the error code in the question text would make the question easier to find. It would also make it more accessible, e.g. to people using screen readers. Therefore, such an edit would not be considered trivial, and I see no reason why it should be rejected/discouraged.

Comment: Thanks for the insight.